# Deklination mehrerer attributiver Adjektive

Tags: adjective-ending

In meinem Grammatik-Duden (4. Auflage, 1984) steht:

> Randnummer 500: Die Deklination mehrerer attributiver Adjektive
>
> Die frühere Regel, daß in diesem Falle beim Dativ Singular […] das zweite der artikellosen Adjektive nach Typ II (schwach) gebeugt werden müsse, gilt nicht mehr:
>
> > bei dunkle*m* bayerische*m* Bier
> >     (und nicht wie früher:)
> >     bei dunkle*m* bayerische*n* Bier
>
> Im Dativ Sing. Mask. und Neutr. wird allerdings das zweite Adjektiv auch noch nach Typ II gebeugt:
>
> > auf schwarze*m* hölzerne*n* Sockel

Nun habe ich zwei Fragen dazu:

1. Ist es sprachliche Wirklichkeit, dass das doppelte Beugen aus dem ersten Beispiel nicht mehr gilt? Intuitiv finde ich die veraltete Form richtig.
2. Gibt es überhaupt einen grammatikalischen Unterschied zwischen dem ersten Beispiel (dunklem bayerischem) und dem zweiten Beispiel (schwarzem hölzernen)? Oder müsste nicht das dunkle bayerische Bier auch in das untere Beispiel verschoben werden?

Comment: Sprachliche Wirklichkeit ist m.E, dass *beides* akzeptabel ist und akzeptiert wird. Früher hätte man einen semantischen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Beugungsformen festmachen können, der nach der Regeländerung aber nicht mehr formulierbar ist.

Comment: @tofro Meinst Du den Unterschied "bei dunklem, bayrischem Bier" also Bier, das dunkel weil bayrisch ist vs. "bei dunklem bayrischen Bier", also Bier, das dunkel und bayrisch ist? Oder was anderes?

Comment: Dazu gibt es mE mehrere bereits gestellte Fragen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ja, das meine ich.

Comment: Ein 33 Jahre altes Grammatikbuch ist natürlich besser als gar keines, aber da Deutsch eine lebende Sprache ist, die sich ständig verändert (und das mit zunehmender Geschwindigkeit), würde ich an deiner Stelle über den Kauf einer aktuelleren Ausgabe nachdenken. Vielleicht noch wichtiger als die Veränderung der Sprache ist der wissenschaftliche Fortschritt, der bei der Untersuchung der Sprache inzwischen stattgefunden hat, und der in alten Büchern natürlich nicht abgebildet ist.

Answer (score 1):

Die alte Regel ist in der Praxis noch viel stärker, sonst würde man auf Grußkarten auch "Alles Gute zum neuem Jahr" schreiben, da hier sehr viel Analogie in diesem Beispiel steckt.

Der Unterschied ist meiner Meinung nach, ob es sich um eine Aufzählung voneinander unabhängiger Eigenschaften handelt oder die erste die zweite näher beschreibt.