# Adjektivendung praktisch/künstlerisch …em oder …en deklinieren

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Fordert der folgende Beispielsatz die Adjektivendung **…em** oder **…en**?

> […] eine spannende Arbeit mit hohem künstlerisch*em* und praktisch*em* Anspruch

oder

> […] eine spannende Arbeit mit hohem künstlerisch*en* und praktisch*en* Anspruch

Comment: Das ist einer der populärsten Fragen. Vielleicht hilft einer der folgenden Links: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24228/zwei-em-endungen-in-adjektiven-hintereinander), [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27650/mit-gutem-roten-wein), [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35158/deklination-mehrerer-attributiver-adjektive).

Comment: @DavidVogt danke, ich wusste nicht, wonach ich suchen sollte bzw. es ist mir nicht gelungen eine Antwort zu finden!

Comment: Ist auch nicht superleicht zu finden. Überleg mal, ob einer der verlinkten Posts deine Frage hinreichend beantwortet. Wenn nicht, könntest du deine Frage noch einmal überarbeiten. Ansonsten kann man sie schließen.